# How can one accomplish this topmenu

Tags: javascript

So I have been trying to get something similar to this topnav menu found on this page: https://www.apotekhjartat.se/

Not sure if this is pure css, javascript or some jquery. (guess its called/reffered as toggle or hide/show div)

I like the way the arrows are displayed if the content is opened or closed and that the content slides down.

If I have a look at the examples on w3schools I can only find that that works with one link...
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Simple markup:

```html
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is my first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is my second link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is my third link</a></li>    
    </ul>    
</header>
    
    
<section id="01" style="display: none">
    <p>This is the conent of the first link</p> 
</section>
    
<section id="02" style="display: none">
    <p>This is the conent of the second link</p> 
</section>
    
<section id="03" style="display: none">
    <p>This is the conent of the third link</p> 
</section>
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction to get something similar to: https://www.apotekhjartat.se/...

Thanks!

Comment: you realise you can easily look at the source code of that site itself to see how it works?

Comment: `"Not sure if this is pure css, javascript or some jquery"`? Funny stuff. You have to know what you're working with to do anything in life.

Comment: Hi guys, well i have been looking on the code itself, seems to be bootstrap framework but I cannot find the javascript which I suppose it is related to the menu itself to see how it works.

Comment: if it's a bootstrap-driven menu, the code which does it will be within the bootstrap Javascript files

Comment: You ought to be able to see what's going on by looking at the event handlers bound to the menu elements and seeing where they go.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is known as a `Sticky Header`.

There are various [libraries](http://plugins.imdanishiqbal.com/sticky-header/), [tutorials](http://www.webtutorialplus.com/sticky-header-on-scroll-jquery/), and [SO Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sticky%20header) that should help you further.

Comment: Hi Joseph, im not after the sticky header itself. I got that covered. Its the menu items that fires up a new div with content (slides down)